# How to Manage State with RxJava in Android using Java (Not Kotlin)

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am attempting to developed an Android application based on the following talk presented by Jake Wharton

```
The State of Managing State with RxJava
21 March 2017 – Devoxx (San Jose, CA, USA)
```

Jake promised a part 2 and/or GITHUB example which I am unable to find (If indeed either exists)

At a high level I can follow/understand the majority of the above talk.

However I have the following questions.

I can see how employing UiEvent, UiModel, Action, and Result keeps concerns separated.

What I am confused about is the following:-

The diagram on slide 194 shows the "flow/stream" of Observables as

```
Android Device -----> Observable<UiEvent> -----> <application code> -----> Observable<Action>  -----> {Backend}
{Backend}      -----> Observable<Result>  -----> <application code> -----> Observable<UiModel> -----> Android Device
```

Slide 210 contains this code snippet, showing how the Result(s) stream is "scan"ned into UiModel

```
SubmitUiModel initialState = SubmitUiModel.idle();
Observable<Result> results = /* ... */;
Observable<SubmitUiModel> uiModels = results.scan(initialState, (state, result) -> {
if (result == CheckNameResult.IN_FLIGHT
|| result == SubmitResult.IN_FLIGHT)
return SubmitUiModel.inProgress();
if (result == CheckNameResult.SUCCESS)
return SubmitUiModel.idle();
if (result == SubmitResult.SUCCESS)
return SubmitUiModel.success();
// TODO handle check name and submit failures...
throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown result: " + result);
});
```

and the final code snippet on slide 215, the code snippet resembles this:-

```
ObservableTransformer<SubmitAction, SubmitResult> submit =
actions -> actions.flatMap(action -> service.setName(action.name)
.map(response -> SubmitResult.SUCCESS)
.onErrorReturn(t -> SubmitResult.failure(t.getMessage()))
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.startWith(SubmitResult.IN_FLIGHT));

ObservableTransformer<CheckNameAction, CheckNameResult> checkName =
actions -> actions.switchMap(action -> action
.delay(200, MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.flatMap(action -> service.checkName(action.name))
.map(response -> CheckNameResult.SUCCESS)
.onErrorReturn(t -> CheckNameResult.failure(t.getMessage()))
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.startWith(CheckNameResult.IN_FLIGHT));
```

which illustrates conversion from Action(s) to Result(s)

what am I missing from this talk/slide-deck on how to combine the UiEvent/UiModel to the Action/Result stream?

The stream is driven by UiEvents
How do you complete the flow from UiEvent(s) to Action back to Result then finally UiModel?

**UPDATE**
Using the Star Wars API I have taken the following approach
I use my UI Events to drive the transformation between UI Events to Results via Actions, then scan the results to map back to UI Model.

Heres my classes and code:-

```
ACTION CLASSES
==============

public abstract class Action<T> {

    Api service = Service.instance();

    final T data;

    public Action(final T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public abstract Observable<Response<String>> execute();
}


public class CheckCharacterAction extends Action<String> {

    public CheckCharacterAction(final String characterName) {
        super(characterName);
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Response<String>> execute() {
        return service.peopleSearch(getData());
    }    
}

public class CheckFilmAction extends Action<String> {    
    public CheckFilmAction(final String filmTitle) {
        super(filmTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Response<String>> execute() {
        return service.filmSearch(getData());
    }    
}

public class SearchAction extends Action<String> {    
    public SearchAction(final String search) {
        super(search);
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<Response<String>>  execute() {
        return service.filmSearch(getData());
    }    
}

EVENT CLASSES
=============
public abstract class UiEvent<T> {

    private final T data;

    public UiEvent(final T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }
}

public class CharacterUiEvent extends UiEvent<String> {
    public CharacterUiEvent(final String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}

public class FilmUiEvent extends UiEvent<String> {
    public FilmUiEvent(final String title) {
        super(title);
    }
}

public class SearchUiEvent extends UiEvent<String> {
    public SearchUiEvent(final String data) {
        super(data);
    }
}

UI MODEL CLASSES
================
public class UiModel<T> {

    public final boolean isProgress;
    public final String message;
    public final boolean isSuccess;
    public T data;

    public UiModel(final boolean isProgress) {
        this.isProgress = isProgress;
        this.message = null;
        this.isSuccess = false;
        this.data = null;
    }

    public UiModel(final T data) {
        this.isProgress = false;
        this.message = null;
        this.isSuccess = true;
        this.data = data;
    }

    public UiModel(final String message) {
        this.isProgress = false;
        this.message = message;
        this.isSuccess = false;
        this.data = null;
    }

    public UiModel(final boolean isProgress, final String message, final boolean isSuccess, final T data) {
        this.isProgress = isProgress;
        this.message = message;
        this.isSuccess = isSuccess;
        this.data = data;
    }
}

public class CharacterUiModel extends UiModel<JsonData> {

    public CharacterUiModel(final boolean isProgress) {
        super(isProgress);
    }

    public CharacterUiModel(final JsonData data) {
        super(data);
    }

    public CharacterUiModel(final String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public CharacterUiModel(final boolean isProgress, final String message, final boolean isSuccess, final JsonData data) {
        super(isProgress, message, isSuccess, data);
    }


    public static CharacterUiModel inProgress() {
        return new CharacterUiModel(true);
    }

    public static CharacterUiModel success(final JsonData data) {
        return new CharacterUiModel(data);
    }

    public static CharacterUiModel failure(final String message) {
        return new CharacterUiModel(message);
    }

}

public class FilmUiModel extends UiModel<JsonData> {


    public FilmUiModel(final boolean isProgress) {
        super(isProgress);
    }

    public FilmUiModel(final JsonData data) {
        super(data);
    }

    public FilmUiModel(final String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public FilmUiModel(final boolean isProgress, final String message, final boolean isSuccess, final JsonData data) {
        super(isProgress, message, isSuccess, data);
    }


    public static FilmUiModel inProgress() {
        return new FilmUiModel(true);
    }

    public static FilmUiModel success(final JsonData data) {
        return new FilmUiModel(data);
    }

    public static FilmUiModel failure(final String message) {
        return new FilmUiModel(message);
    }

}

public class SearchUiModel extends UiModel<JsonData> {

    private SearchUiModel(final boolean isProgress) {
        super(isProgress);
    }

    private SearchUiModel(final JsonData data) {
        super(data);
    }

    private SearchUiModel(final String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    private SearchUiModel(final boolean isProgress, final String message, final boolean isSuccess, final JsonData data) {
        super(isProgress, message, isSuccess, data);
    }

    public static SearchUiModel idle() {
        return new SearchUiModel(false, null, false, null);
    }

    public static SearchUiModel inProgress() {
        return new SearchUiModel(true);
    }

    public static SearchUiModel success(final JsonData data) {
        return new SearchUiModel(data);
    }

    public static SearchUiModel failure(final String message) {
        return new SearchUiModel(message);
    }
}


RESULT CLASSES
==============

public abstract class Result<T> {

    public enum LIFECYCLE {
        DEPARTURE_LOUNGE,
        IN_FLIGHT,
        LANDED_SAFELY,
        CRASHED_BURNED
    }

    final LIFECYCLE lifecycle;
    final T data;
    final String errorMessage;

    public Result(final LIFECYCLE lifecycle, final T data, final String errorMessage) {
        this.lifecycle = lifecycle;
        this.data = data;
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }

    public T getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }

    public LIFECYCLE getLifecycle() {
        return lifecycle;
    }
}

public class CharacterResult extends Result<JsonData> {

    private CharacterResult(final LIFECYCLE lifecycle, final JsonData data, final String errorMessage) {
        super(lifecycle, data, errorMessage);
    }

    private CharacterResult(final LIFECYCLE lifecycle) {
        super(lifecycle, null, null);
    }

    public static CharacterResult departureLounge() {
        return new CharacterResult(LIFECYCLE.DEPARTURE_LOUNGE);
    }

    public static CharacterResult inflight() {
        return new CharacterResult(LIFECYCLE.IN_FLIGHT);
    }

    public static CharacterResult landedSafely(final JsonData data) {
        return new CharacterResult(LIFECYCLE.LANDED_SAFELY, data, null);
    }

    public static CharacterResult crashedBurned(final String errorMessage) {
        return new CharacterResult(LIFECYCLE.CRASHED_BURNED, null, errorMessage);
    }
}


public class FilmResult extends Result<JsonData> {

    private FilmResult(final LIFECYCLE lifecycle, final JsonData data, final String errorMessage) {
        super(lifecycle, data, errorMessage);
    }

    private FilmResult(final LIFECYCLE lifecycle) {
        super(lifecycle, null, null);
    }

    public static FilmResult departureLounge() {
        return new FilmResult(LIFECYCLE.DEPARTURE_LOUNGE);
    }

    public static FilmResult inflight() {
        return new FilmResult(LIFECYCLE.IN_FLIGHT);
    }

    public static FilmResult landedSafely(final JsonData data) {
        return new FilmResult(LIFECYCLE.LANDED_SAFELY, data, null);
    }

    public static FilmResult crashedBurned(final String errorMessage) {
        return new FilmResult(LIFECYCLE.CRASHED_BURNED, null, errorMessage);
    }
}

public class SearchResult extends Result<JsonData> {

    private SearchResult(final LIFECYCLE lifecycle, final JsonData data, final String errorMessage) {
        super(lifecycle, data, errorMessage);
    }

    private SearchResult(final LIFECYCLE lifecycle) {
        super(lifecycle, null, null);
    }

    public static SearchResult departureLounge() {
        return new SearchResult(LIFECYCLE.DEPARTURE_LOUNGE);
    }

    public static SearchResult inflight() {
        return new SearchResult(LIFECYCLE.IN_FLIGHT);
    }

    public static SearchResult landedSafely(final JsonData data) {
        return new SearchResult(LIFECYCLE.LANDED_SAFELY, data, null);
    }

    public static SearchResult crashedBurned(final String errorMessage) {
        return new SearchResult(LIFECYCLE.CRASHED_BURNED, null, errorMessage);
    }
}
```

I then set up my Rx Streams as follows from my Activity `onCreate()` method:-

```
   final Observable<SearchUiEvent> searchEvents = RxView.clicks(activityMainBinding.searchButton)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(ignored -> new SearchUiEvent(activityMainBinding.filmTitle.getText().toString()));

    final Observable<FilmUiEvent> filmEvents = RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(activityMainBinding.filmTitle)
            .skipInitialValue()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .delay(1000, MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(text -> new FilmUiEvent(text.view().getText().toString()));

    final Observable<CharacterUiEvent> characterEvents = RxTextView.afterTextChangeEvents(activityMainBinding.people)
            .skipInitialValue()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .delay(200, MILLISECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .map(text -> new CharacterUiEvent(text.view().getText().toString()));

    /**
     *
     */
    final Observable<UiEvent> uiEvents = Observable.merge(searchEvents, filmEvents, characterEvents);

    /*********
     *
     */

    final ObservableTransformer<SearchUiEvent, SearchResult> searchAction =
            events -> events.flatMap(event -> new SearchAction(event.getData()).execute().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
                    .map(response -> SearchResult.landedSafely(new JsonData(response.body())))
                    .onErrorReturn(throwable -> SearchResult.crashedBurned(throwable.getMessage()))
                    .startWith(SearchResult.inflight());

    final ObservableTransformer<FilmUiEvent, FilmResult> filmAction =
            events -> events.flatMap(event -> new CheckFilmAction(event.getData()).execute().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
                    .map(response -> FilmResult.landedSafely(new JsonData(response.body())))
                    .onErrorReturn(throwable -> FilmResult.crashedBurned(throwable.getMessage()))
                    .startWith(FilmResult.inflight());

    final ObservableTransformer<CharacterUiEvent, CharacterResult> characterAction =
            events -> events.flatMap(event -> new CheckCharacterAction(event.getData()).execute().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()))
                    .map(response -> CharacterResult.landedSafely(new JsonData(response.body())))
                    .onErrorReturn(throwable -> CharacterResult.crashedBurned(throwable.getMessage()))
                    .startWith(CharacterResult.inflight());

    final ObservableTransformer<UiEvent, ? extends Result> whatever = events -> events.publish(shared -> Observable.merge(
            shared.ofType(SearchUiEvent.class).compose(searchAction),
            shared.ofType(CharacterUiEvent.class).compose(characterAction),
            shared.ofType(FilmUiEvent.class).compose(filmAction)));

    /**
     *
     */
    final UiModel initialState = SearchUiModel.idle();

    final Observable<? extends Result> results = uiEvents.compose(whatever).doOnSubscribe(COMPOSITE_DISPOSABLE::add);

    final Observable<UiModel> models = results.scan(initialState, (state, result) -> {
        Log.e(TAG, "scan() state = " + state + " result = " + result);
        if (result.getLifecycle().equals(SearchResult.LIFECYCLE.DEPARTURE_LOUNGE) ||
                result.getLifecycle().equals(CharacterResult.LIFECYCLE.DEPARTURE_LOUNGE) ||
                result.getLifecycle().equals(FilmResult.LIFECYCLE.DEPARTURE_LOUNGE)) {
            return SearchUiModel.idle();
        }

        if (result.getLifecycle().equals(SearchResult.LIFECYCLE.IN_FLIGHT) ||
                result.getLifecycle().equals(CharacterResult.LIFECYCLE.IN_FLIGHT) ||
                result.getLifecycle().equals(FilmResult.LIFECYCLE.IN_FLIGHT)) {
            return SearchUiModel.inProgress();
        }

        if (result.getLifecycle().equals(SearchResult.LIFECYCLE.LANDED_SAFELY) ||
                result.getLifecycle().equals(CharacterResult.LIFECYCLE.LANDED_SAFELY) ||
                result.getLifecycle().equals(FilmResult.LIFECYCLE.LANDED_SAFELY)) {
            return SearchUiModel.success((JsonData) result.getData());
        }

        if (result.getLifecycle().equals(SearchResult.LIFECYCLE.CRASHED_BURNED) ||
                result.getLifecycle().equals(CharacterResult.LIFECYCLE.CRASHED_BURNED) ||
                result.getLifecycle().equals(FilmResult.LIFECYCLE.CRASHED_BURNED)) {
            return SearchUiModel.failure(result.getErrorMessage());
        }


        return null;

    });

    models.doOnSubscribe(COMPOSITE_DISPOSABLE::add).subscribe(model -> report(model), throwable -> error(throwable));
```

As soon as my activity displays I get the following logs:-

```
2018-10-09 14:22:33.310 D/MainActivity: report() called with: model = [UiModel{isProgress=false, message='null', isSuccess=false, data=null}]
2018-10-09 14:22:33.311 E/MainActivity: scan() state = UiModel{isProgress=false, message='null', isSuccess=false, data=null} result = SearchResult{lifecycle=IN_FLIGHT, data=null, errorMessage='null'}
2018-10-09 14:22:33.311 D/MainActivity: report() called with: model = [UiModel{isProgress=true, message='null', isSuccess=false, data=null}]
2018-10-09 14:22:33.313 E/MainActivity: scan() state = UiModel{isProgress=true, message='null', isSuccess=false, data=null} result = CharacterResult{lifecycle=IN_FLIGHT, data=null, errorMessage='null'}
2018-10-09 14:22:33.313 D/MainActivity: report() called with: model = [UiModel{isProgress=true, message='null', isSuccess=false, data=null}]
2018-10-09 14:22:33.313 E/MainActivity: scan() state = UiModel{isProgress=true, message='null', isSuccess=false, data=null} result = FilmResult{lifecycle=IN_FLIGHT, data=null, errorMessage='null'}
2018-10-09 14:22:33.313 D/MainActivity: report() called with: model = [UiModel{isProgress=true, message='null', isSuccess=false, data=null}]
```

Im guessing I get these `IN FLIGHT` results due to my `.startWith()` statements.

When I either click my Search button or enter any text in my EditText views I see the following logs:-

```
2018-10-09 14:55:19.463 E/MainActivity: scan() state = UiModel{isProgress=false, message='null', isSuccess=true, data=com.test.model.JsonData@5e0b6f1} result = FilmResult{lifecycle=LANDED_SAFELY, data=com.test.model.JsonData@8ae4d86, errorMessage='null'}
2018-10-09 14:55:19.463 D/MainActivity: report() called with: model = [UiModel{isProgress=false, message='null', isSuccess=true, data=com.test.model.JsonData@8ae4d86}]
```

Why do I not see "IN FLIGHT" then "LANDED SAFELY"?

I only get "LANDED SAFELY"

Is my approach to transforming between UI Event -> Action -> Result -> UI Model anywhere close to what is described by Mr J Wharton?

Where have I gone wrong?

**UPDATE (II)**

My mistake was to not include all my downstream Rx within the `.flatmap()` operation.

**CLARIFICATION**

Does this pattern of UI Event ---> Action ---> Result ---> UI Model still apply for cases where there is no "Backend" as such? e.g. a Home screen could present the user with a number of options (buttons) to navigate to lower level screens within the application. The UI Event would be "Button Click" the UI Model would return with the associated Activity class to employ with the `startActivity()` method call.

How can I amalgamate the UI input events of a login screen into a single stream of UI events where I have two EditText fields (User Name and Password) and a Login Button.
I would want the button click UI event to contain the user name and user password  entered. If I was using RxBinding to process the EditTexts and the Login button click I cannot see how I can combine these three Observables into my UI event stream and have the EditTexts validated to ensure they have data entered and then pass this user entered data to my back end login API (or maybe Google Sign In for example)

Comment: Hi Hector, Did you see this project https://github.com/nmwilk/soms-jw?,  It seems related to the Jake talk.

Comment: @Hector Can you please tell what is your original problem?

Comment: @Kousic My problem is Jakes' talk is incomplete. Some of the code examples have small errors. However the biggest issue with his presentation is that it does not explain the entire cycle of how to transition from UiEvent -> Action -> Result -> Ui Model, backed up with code snippets. From the comments attached to the youTube video of this talk and elsewhere (e.g. Reddit) many other developers are of a similar opinion.

Comment: For **How can I amalgamate the UI input events of a login screen into a single stream of UI events where I have two EditText fields (User Name and Password) and a Login Button. I would want the button click UI event to contain the user name and user password entered...** try this:                                              
[Retrofit, a Simple HTTP Client for Android and Java](https://www.sitepoint.com/retrofit-a-simple-http-client-for-android-and-java/). I hope this will be helpful!

Answer (score 2):

(I was adding a comment but it was too long)

I cannot help with the talks and so on presented by Jake. But regarding your last question:

> Does this pattern of UI Event ---> Action ---> Result ---> UI Model
>   still apply for cases where there is no "Backend" as such?

It does, it is just that the *backend* is your application state *repository*.

In this kind of architecture there should only be one place of truth for your application: be it a backend, a local database, a combination of both or whatever solution is appropriate for your usecase.

---

Having that in mind your *Action streams* should modify the state either by doing calls to the backend, posting changes to a database or writing elements in the sharedSetting. Similarly, changes in your state should trigger sending Results down your streams.

The specific details would depend on what you use as a source of truth for your application.

Comment: I use a Realm local database as my source of truth, however I've updated my question with some UI only scenarios that I think need to use "Dummy" Action/Result pairs

Answer (score 1):

**DataFlow and State**

It uses mainly Paco and Jake Wharton RxState idea plus added some more stuff.

- To use UiEvent → Action, Result → UiModel transformers and always act
  on a single state with the help of RxJava operators (Forming a single
  stream of events, then based on their types handling actions with
  different transformers, then combine results again, modifying the
  state and then finally render it on the UI.
- or not to use transformers and make it a little bit “simpler”.

So here is the “full” view model code without using any transformers:

```
class SomeViewModel(private val someRepository: SomeRepository): ViewModel() {

    val uiEvents: PublishSubject<UiEvent> = PublishSubject.create()
    val outputState: MutableLiveData<Result<UiState>> = MutableLiveData()

    init {
        uiEvents.subscribe {
            when (it) {
                    is FirstEvent -> getSomeResultsFromRepo(it.id)
                    is SecondEvent -> handleSecondEvent()
                }
        }
    }

    fun getSomeResultsFromRepo(id: String) {
        someRepository.getResult(id)
                .map { UiState(it) }
                .map { Result.success(it) }
                .startWith(Result.loading())
                .onErrorReturn { handleError(it) }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    outputState.postValue(it)
                })
    }

    fun handleSecondEvent() {
        /* do something here */
        someRepository.getSomeOtherResult()
                .map { UiState(it) }
                .map { Result.success(it) }
                .startWith(Result.loading())
                .onErrorReturn { handleError(it) }
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    outputState.postValue(it)
                })
    }

    private fun handleError(error: Throwable): Result<UiState> {
        return if (error is RetrofitException) {
            when (error.kind) {
                RetrofitException.Kind.NETWORK -> Result.failure(NetworkError(error))
                RetrofitException.Kind.HTTP -> Result.failure(ServerError(error))
                RetrofitException.Kind.UNEXPECTED -> Result.failure(UnknownError(error))
                else -> Result.failure(UnknownError(error))
            }
        } else {
            Result.failure(UnknownError(error))
        }
    }

    class Factory @Inject constructor(private val someRepo: SomeRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
        override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return SomeViewModel(someRepo) as T
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see here 2 streams: a uiEvents (1st stream) which gets all the input events from the UI. As long as the UI exists it will be catching those events. Based on the event types it calls some repository functions (use cases) that are returning some response and then they are updating the model (2nd stream) with one of the possible outcomes: Success, Error or Loading.

Also transform the errors in API to so called RetrofitErrors, and based on their type it can show different error messages to the User.

There is some duplication as well that can be avoided easily, but what I wanted to show here is that it always start with a Loading result, then either a Success or an Error.

One of the most important thing is that this way "**To keep state in the stream, which is a LiveData.**"

One benefit of this setup (just like using a BehaviourSubject) is that it will always return the last state — on orientation change it is very useful as it just loads the last available state.

Also it is highly testable as each piece can be tested in separation with providing mocked repo or view and it is also very easy to debug as we always have a current state in the stream.